# What is the best way to create backup in an existing gitlab and restore the same backup in a new gitlab server?

Tags: backup-restoration, gitlab

What is the best way to backup and restore gitlab incuding all repositories, commit comments, wall comments, wiki etc.

Comment: If I knew what to try, would I ask the question?

Comment: There are two major problems with this question - (1) "best" is very subjective. The "best" solution depends on your environment and needs. (2) Server Fault does not exist to do all the work for you. [You are expected to come to the table with research, and at least a little effort expended to find a solution on your own](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault), and then to ask specific questions.

Comment: This looks like a valid question to me (and one which I too am wanting an answer to currently). Closing it as "not constructive" is ironically a lot less constructive of a thing to do than what the OP did by asking the question. Who cares if "best" is subjective? Let people answer the question by submitting the best way (in their eyes) to perform this task that they know of.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md):

> A backup creates an archive file that contains the database, all repositories and all attachments.
>   This archive will be saved in backup_path (see `config/gitlab.yml`).
>
> The filename will be `[TIMESTAMP]_gitlab_backup.tar`. This timestamp can be used to restore an specific backup.

`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`

Comment: Thank you, and where is the backup path?

Comment: This answer is only for the omnibus edition, and not if you installed gitlab from source

Comment: Can i issue this command while the GitLab has users working on wikipages doing push and pulls and stuff?

Comment: For omnibus version you can define your backup path via:
`gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/mnt/backup"`

Comment: So it's not a problem to restore the backup to a newer version of GitLab? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md says "You can only restore a backup to exactly the same version of GitLab on which it was created." Guess I'll just have to try it...

Comment: @TylerRick, how did you go with restoring to a newer version? I just migrated mine across to a new server, but couldn't bear the thought of losing anything so I installed an old version of GitLab on the new server, and then will manually upgrade. (I'm moving away from a source-based installation to an omnibus installation).

Comment: @XtraSimplicity I don't think I actually ended up trying it. IIRC, we downgraded database version temporarily so they matched...